# How to grab last character in a regex with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to grab the last space and what follows it on a line using grep.

This grab me the first space :

```
echo "toto tata titi" | grep -o " .*$"
```

In Java I would have used the non-greedy operator but it does not seem to work :

```
echo "toto tata titi" | grep -o " .*?$"
```

It return nothing

The expected result is `titi`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `.` with `[^ ]`, which matches everything but space. Then it can be greedy.

```
echo "toto tata titi" | grep -o " [^ ]*$"
```

(If you want `grep` to use extended regexes, either use `egrep` or `grep -E`.)

Comment: Your regex do what I wanted to do, thank you. But do you know why mine do not work even with -E ?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe: Because the regex is applied to the subject string from left to right, so it starts on the first space, gradually expands until the end and thus succeeds. No need to try any further positions.

Comment: @Jean: The `/ .*?$/` match first finds the space and starts matching from there. It keeps matching until the end of the string and is done. Non-greediness only comes into play when the interpreter has to decide whether to continue looking for the current unit (`.`) or to match with the next instead. It does _not_ backtrack until it finds the shortest solution.

Comment: @tim-pietzcker @tim-nordenfur thank to both of you, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you are doing  is just getting the first character of the last field. The more approachable method than regex is using a tool that can split strings into fields and doing "substring-ing".

```
$ echo "toto tata titi" | awk '{print substr($NF,0,1)}'
t


$ echo "toto tata titi" | ruby -ane 'puts $F[-1][0]'
t
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I just saw a better answer to this post, but posting this anyway, as it might be helpful if you want to do something more complex, like substituting things.

Another way to do this as is to use the `sed`command and let it substitute (with the `s` command first in the regex) everything except that which you want (which is collected into the variable `\1` by the parentheses:

```
echo "toto tata titi" | sed -r "s/.*( .*?)$/\1/"
```